# How to open a TrueCrypt volume quickly on a Mac?

Tags: macos, mac, truecrypt

Whenever I need to access data stored in the TrueCrypt-protected volume on my MacBook, I need to start TrueCrypt from the Dock, select the volume file, click mount, enter the password and then open a Finder window and browse to the volume. I want a quicker way, e.g. double-click something on the desktop (and/or press a hotkey combination), enter the password and have a Finder window pop up.

I have done an extensive research on the TrueCrypt website, Apple Automator and some other approaches, but nothing really seems come up.

Has anyone realized the approach described ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I run this one-line bash script which will get you directly to TC's password dialog.  Without much more effort than embedding it into an Applescript, you should be able to expand it to include opening a Finder window to the mounted volume, and saving as a clickable application:

> /Applications/TrueCrypt.app/Contents/MacOS/TrueCrypt --mount <path-to-your-TC-archive>

Comment: The --mount parameter doesn't even seem required. Also,
/Applications/TrueCrypt.app/Contents/MacOS/TrueCrypt --dismount <path-to-your-TC-archive> dismounts the volume.
Stored both apps in ~/bin (/usr/local/bin or /Applications/... would be system-wide alternatives), duplicated them (i.e. created a symlink), moved the duplicate / symlink to the desktop and gave it some nice icons.